# i get this error "expexted string or buffer"

Tags: python-3.x

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\file.txt")

text = file.read()
def ie_preprocess(text):

  sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(text)
  sents=sent_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  print(sents)
  word_tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
  words =nltk.word_tokenize(sents)
  print(words)

  tagges = nltk.pos_tag(words)
  print(tagges)

ie_preprocess(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

`nltk.word_tokenize()` takes in `text` which is expected to be a string, but you are passing in `sents` which is a list of sentences.

Instead, you want:

```
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

If you would like to tokenize each sentence into a list of words and get this back as a list of lists, you could use

```
words = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sents]
```